# vue js compile scss to css

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I have a vue js project with scss files.

I would like to compile the scss files to css and put them in the public folder.

How should I do it please?

vue.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.entry('theme')
            .add('./src/assets/app.scs')
            .end();
    },
    css: {
        extract: {
            filename: 'app.css',
            chunkFilename: 'css/app.css'
        },
        modules: false,
        sourceMap: true
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
            }
        }
    }
};
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Webpack, I think your best option is to use vue-loader + sass-loader with a specific option to extract the compiled css.

- [vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/#manual-setup) is in charge of splitting your Single File Components (`.vue` files) into HTML / Script / Style and provide each part to the correct loader.
- [sass-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) (used with `dart-sass`) will compile your sass down to css.
- Use `MiniCssExtractPlugin` to specify where to extract the final css: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#extracts-css-into-separate-files